# Linux - gawk line numbers on multiple lines

Tags: linux, gawk

I have this gawk script that is supposed to output text in this format:

```
line 1: I am just a poor boy
line 1 reversed: boy poor a just am I
```

Here is the script:

```
BEGIN {print ""}
{
  printf "Line %d: %s\n", NR, $0;
  lineCount++;

  for (i = NF; i >= 1; i--)
    printf  "%s " , $i;

 printf "\n\n";
}
END {printf ""}
```

My question is how do I get "Line x reversed: " on the reversed line?

Comment: You see how to use `printf`, why not add another one? (hint, hint, just before the `for` loop?) . Also, what are you using `LineCount` for? Delete that! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

this works...

```
$ awk '{print "line " NR ":", $0; 
        for(i=1; i<=NF/2; i++) {k=NF-i+1; t=$i; $i=$k; $k=t}   
        print "line " NR " reversed: " $0}' file

line 1: I am just a poor boy
line 1 reversed: boy poor a just am I
```